# set_max_velocity_scaling_factor in a cartesian path

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

For a Nextage open on Ubuntu 14 and Ros Indigo , I want to control de velocity in a Cartesian path using waypoints and compute_cartesian_path.
I used set_max_velocity_scaling_factor, but it is not working. As well, it is not giving any error, I change the factor but the robot is running always with the same speed.

I tried set_max_velocity_scaling_factor in a joint path and it is working. It seems that is not working for Cartesian pathes.

Here is my phyton code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# @file     nextage_moveit_waypoint.py   #
# @brief    Nextage Move it demo program #
# @author   Amir                 #
# @date     2017/01/26                   #
from hironx_ros_bridge.ros_client import ROS_Client
# This should come earlier than later import.
# See http://code.google.com/p/rtm-ros-robotics/source/detail?r=6773
from nextage_ros_bridge import nextage_client

from hrpsys import rtm
import argparse

import sys
import moveit_commander
import copy
import rospy
import geometry_msgs.msg
import unittest
import moveit_msgs.msg

def main():
    rospy.init_node("moveit_command_sender")

    robot = moveit_commander.RobotCommander()
    
    print "=" * 10, " Robot Groups:"
    print robot.get_group_names()

    print "=" * 10, " Printing robot state"
    print robot.get_current_state()
    print "=" * 10 

    rarm = moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander("right_arm")
    larm = moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander("left_arm")
    both= moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander("botharms")
    rhand= moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander("right_hand")
    lhand= moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander("left_hand")
    lartor= moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander("left_arm_torso")
    larm.set_max_velocity_scaling_factor(.01)   


    print "=" * 15, " Right arm ", "=" * 15
    print "=" * 10, " Reference frame: %s" % rarm.get_planning_frame()
    print "=" * 10, " Reference frame: %s" % rarm.get_end_effector_link()
    
    print "=" * 15, " Left ight arm ", "=" * 15
    print "=" * 10, " Reference frame: %s" % larm.get_planning_frame()
    print "=" * 10, " Reference frame: %s" % larm.get_end_effector_link()

    #Right Arm Initial Pose
    rarm_initial_pose = rarm.get_current_pose().pose
    print "=" * 10, " Printing Right Hand initial pose: "
    print rarm_initial_pose

    #Light Arm Initial Pose
    larm_initial_pose = larm.get_current_pose().pose    
    print "=" * 10, " Printing Left Hand initial pose: "
    print larm_initial_pose

    print robot1.get_hand_version()
    robot1.handlight_r(True)
    robot1.handlight_l(True)
    ## Cartesian Paths
    ## ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ## You can plan a cartesian path directly by specifying a list of waypoints 
    ## for the end-effector to go through.
    waypoints = []

    # start with the current pose
    waypoints.append(larm.get_current_pose().pose)

    # first orient gripper and move forward (+x)
    wpose = geometry_msgs.msg.Pose()
    #wpose.orientation.w = 1.0
    wpose.position.x = waypoints[0].position.x + 0.15
    wpose.position.y = waypoints[0].position.y
    wpose.position.z = waypoints[0].position.z
    wpose.orientation.x = 0.0
    wpose.orientation.y = -0.707
    wpose.orientation.z = 0.0
    wpose.orientation.w = 0.707

    waypoints.append(copy.deepcopy(wpose))

    # second move up
    wpose.position.z += 0.2
    waypoints.append(copy.deepcopy(wpose))

    # third move to the side
    wpose.position.y -= 0.2
    waypoints.append(copy.deepcopy(wpose))

    wpose.position.x = waypoints[0].position.x
    wpose.position.y = waypoints[0].position.y
    wpose.position.z = waypoints[0].position.z
    wpose.orientation.x = 0.0
    wpose.orientation.y = -0.707
    wpose.orientation.z = 0.0
    wpose.orientation.w = 0.707
    waypoints.append(copy.deepcopy(wpose))
    print waypoints

    ## We want the cartesian path to be interpolated at a resolution of 1 cm
    ## which is why we will specify 0.01 as the eef_step in cartesian
    ## translation.  We will specify the jump threshold as 0.0, effectively
    ## disabling it.
    larm.set_max_velocity_scaling_factor(0.01)  
    (plan1, fraction) = larm.compute_cartesian_path(
                           waypoints,   # waypoints to follow
                           0.01,        # eef_step
                           0.0)         # jump_threshold
                           
    print "============ Waiting while RVIZ displays plan3..."
    print rospy.Time.now() 
    rospy.sleep(1)
    print larm.get_known_constraints()
    larm.set_max_velocity_scaling_factor(0.01)  
    larm.execute(plan1)
    
    robot1.handlight_r(False)
    robot1.handlight_l(False)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='hiro command line interpreters')
    parser.add_argument('--host', help='corba name server hostname')
    parser.add_argument('--port', help='corba name server port number')
    parser.add_argument('--modelfile', help='robot model file nmae')
    parser.add_argument('--robot', help='robot modlule name (RobotHardware0 for real robot, Robot()')
    parser.add_argument('--dio_ver', help="Version of digital I/O. Only users "
                        "whose robot was shipped before Aug 2014 need to "
                        "define this, and the value should be '0.4.2'.")
    args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
    print args
    print unknown

    if args.host:
        rtm.nshost = args.host
    if args.port:
        rtm.nsport = args.port
    if not args.robot:
        args.robot = "RobotHardware0" if args.host else "HiroNX(Robot)0"
    if not args.modelfile:
        args.modelfile = "/opt/jsk/etc/NEXTAGE/model/main.wrl" if args.host else "" 

    print args.host
    print rtm.nshost

    # support old style format
    if len(unknown) >= 2:
        args.robot = unknown[0]
        args.modelfile = unknown[1]
    robot1 = nxc = nextage_client.NextageClient()
    robot1.init(robotname=args.robot, url=args.modelfile) #This launch hrpsys

    robot1.set_hand_version('0.4.2')

    #ROS Client.
    #ros = ROS_Client()

    try:
        main()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

I used set_max_velocity_scaling_factor here before compute_cartesian_path and execute, but I checked it once before each command and it doesn change anything.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258127/set_max_velocity_scaling_factor-in-a-cartesian-path/) by [shzargar](https://answers.ros.org/users/29686/shzargar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-03-28

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-03-30**:
Could you update your question with a self-contained code so that we can run it on our computers? I want to see if I can reproduce the issue but imports and variables are not known with the current snippet so that I can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The plain and simple answer to this question is:

This doesn't work because nobody required and/or implemented it until now.
The `GetCartesianPath.srv` ROS service offered by the `move_group` does not support a `max_velocity_scaling_factor` in its request section and the `MoveGroupCommander` uses that service to compute the cartesian trajectory.

So either you have to implement support for this in there, or you have to live with the full-speed trajectory you receive and re-scale the time parameterization afterwards.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2018-09-19**:
Would be really helpful to have code snippets for that here. Related: https://answers.ros.org/question/288989/moveit-velocity-scaling-for-cartesian-path/

**Comment by [cpdef](https://answers.ros.org/users/53813/cpdef/) on 2020-04-21**:
@fvd
This is how i did it using the tutorial code:

```
#include <tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.h>
#include <moveit/trajectory_processing/iterative_time_parameterization.h>
#include <moveit/robot_trajectory/robot_trajectory.h>
...
  // create cartesian path as in the tutorial
  moveit_msgs::RobotTrajectory trajectory;
  moveit_msgs::RobotTrajectory trajectory_slow;
    ...
  // add timing Note: you have to convert it to a RobotTrajectory Object (not message) and back
  trajectory_processing::IterativeParabolicTimeParameterization iptp(100, 0.05);
  robot_trajectory::RobotTrajectory r_trajec(move_group.getRobotModel(), PLANNING_GROUP);
  r_trajec.setRobotTrajectoryMsg(*move_group.getCurrentState(), trajectory);
  iptp.computeTimeStamps(r_trajec, 1, 1);
  r_trajec.getRobotTrajectoryMsg(trajectory);
  iptp.computeTimeStamps(r_trajec, 0.03, 0.03);
  r_trajec.getRobotTrajectoryMsg(trajectory_slow);
```

**Comment by [benedikt](https://answers.ros.org/users/97198/benedikt/) on 2022-05-05**:
Thanks, this works for me. I just had to change the message namespace to get it running with Moveit2 (Galactic binary).

```
moveit_msgs::msg::RobotTrajectory trajectory;
moveit_msgs::msg::RobotTrajectory trajectory_slow;
```